# Multiple List Styling

Tags: html, html-lists

I am having trouble styling a couple different lists.  I am designing and developing a site for my father in law, and the first list I have is the nav, which I want to display inline under the header.  The second list is in an aside which displays to the right.  When I added the second list, the nav list stopped displaying inline and only displays vertically.  No matter what I do, I cannot get this to work.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap the lists in separate divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<nav>
<a href="/Nav 1/">Nav 1</a> |
<a href="/Nav 2/">Nav 2</a> |
<a href="/Nav 3/">Nav 3</a> |
<a href="/Nav 4/">Nav 4</a>
</nav>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
<ul>
  <li>right 1</li>
  <li>right 2</li>
  <li>right 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```